# How can I create search with views to serch between 2 fields

Tags: views, 8, search

I create a plain field for body and a plain field for description.

now create view to search between title, body and description.

I use "Combine fields filter" but in "Choose fields to combine for filtering" box just show "Content: title".

I add body and description fields in fields section, but not change.

Who can help me ?

Drupal 8

Comment: Who can help me?

Comment: When you install Search API, enable the submodule Database Search and Database Search Default you get a working search solution with a view preinstalled which can do this out of the box.

Comment: I think someone should open an RFC for Search API + DB in core to replace core search which isn't that useful or flexible. This is exactly the approach I would take .